# Add a list to AutoComplete Jquery

Tags: jquery

I follow [this tutorial](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-3-mvc-autocomplete-json-tutorial/) and i have a jquery autocomplete, the only difference is that I import my data from database not from an `ArrayList` as in the tutorial.

The problem is that my database is full and when i insert a letter the autocomplete show me all names begin with this letter in one list and my page height become big. for resolving the problem I want to put my data into a list with scroll bar.

How to do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any option at [API Documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) that suggest you to set a `maxLength` or something like that. If I'm not wrong, you could set a max height and overflow properties into a new CSS file, for your list element and I think it will work for what you want to do.

**UPDATED**

Here is the element that works as list:

`<ul class="ui-autocomplete ui-front ui-menu ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" id="ui-id-1" tabindex="0" style="display: none; top: 29px; left: 67px; width: 273px;">`

Inside of it you can see a lot of `<li>` depending on the data recieved. What I suggested to you is to set a `max-height: XXpx;` and an `overflow-y: scroll;` property to any of the current classes that already have the 'list container' (I recommend `.ui-autocomplete`, because the other ones are shared with other jQuery-UI elements) into the new CSS file, that you should have created as I said earlier, and you can try to 'hack' it in that way.

**DIDN'T TESTED**

Comment: That is in which file please ?

Comment: @Souad I think it was not really clear and I will update it, but I meant that you create a new CSS file and put there something like `.ui-autocomplete {max-height: 200px;}`. I selected that class because it's the only one that it's not shared with any of other elements of jQuery-UI and `200px` was only as example, set whatever size that you need.

Comment: When I test that the first results are into the list container but the rest  are shown out of the list.

Comment: @Souad Forgot that you have to put `overflow-y: scroll` property too :P my bad.